# Comparing a list with haskell

Tags: haskell

I tried to write a Haskell function, where an element will be compared with a list.
Seemed to be so easy, but it is not working.

```
zeich :: Char -> Bool

zeich x =   elem x ['a','v','b']
```

Also how should I do the datatype? So that you also can enter numbers?

Comment: What is "not working" about it?

Comment: What is not working here? What datatype are you referring to? Where do you want to enter numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `zeich` function is just fine, a quick `ghci` session gives:

```
λ: let zeich :: Char -> Bool; zeich x = elem x ['a', 'v', 'b']
λ: zeich 'b'
True
λ: zeich 'c'
False
```

If you want to store characters *and* numbers in your list you'll need to devise a new type which can accomodate values of either type, e.g.

```
λ: data Element = Letter Char | Number Int deriving Eq
```

Using which you could then define a `zeich2` number which accepts values of type `Element`:

```
λ: let zeich2 :: Element -> Bool; zeich2 x = elem x [Letter 'a', Number 3, Letter 'b']
λ: zeich2 (Letter 'a')
True
λ: zeich2 (Number 3)
True
λ: zeich2 (Number 4)
False
```

Comment: Ah, I saw my fault. Always left out '  ' in ghci. 
Is it possibly to write a function, where you can just typ a letter without ' '?

Comment: No. Letters without '' are identifiers.